# Issues loading in json data from API in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, mean-stack

I am working on a project where we are building a website using the MEAN stack. I am currently working on the front end and am attempting to read in data from an API and storing that data within an array that I can then access and use. I am running into a very odd issue.

I am aiming to load in an array of data containing latitude and longitude coordinates of all the countries in the world.

I have a service that looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Country } from '../models/country';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  REST_API_SERVER = 'http://localhost:3000/countries/getCountries';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getCountryData() : Observable<Country[]>{

    return this.httpClient.get<Country[]>(this.REST_API_SERVER);
      
  }
}
```

Where `Country` is a class with certain attributes.

I am then accessing this function and using it by doing the following in my component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, HostListener, Host } from '@angular/core';
import { Country } from '../models/country';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';

export class GlobeComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  listOfCountries!: Country[];

  constructor(private countryService : DataService) {
  }

ngOnInit() {
   
    this.countryService.getCountryData().subscribe((countries) => {
      this.listOfCountries = countries;
    });
}
```

I then try to access `listOfCountries` but am unable to. For example, if I say:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.listOfCountries.length; i++)
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

However, if in `ngOnInit()` function I include the following line:

```
console.log("Country printed in ngOnInit : " + this.listOfCountries[0].Entity);
```

It magically starts working. BUT... I get a new error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at GlobeComponent.ngOnInit
```

I am really confused as to why this is happening. Why does console.log populate the array? But why does it continue to claim that the array is undefined even though it is working? After including the console.log, I can access and use the array as normal. But I do not want to keep this console.log, so any help as to where I am going wrong would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please do some basic debugging. Use `console.log()` to make sure your variables contain what you expect them to contain.

Comment: Please, show the full component's code. I'd bet that you have problems with asynchrony.

Comment: @ChrisG I have tried using console.log but the issue is that the array is not being recognised as an array.

Comment: @Lynx242 thank you for the help, here is the full component code: https://github.com/jess-mw/desk23/blob/threejs/src/app/globe/globe.component.ts

Comment: `the array is not being recognised as an array` then it's not an array. Let's be clear: loading something from the server takes a bit, and the data is loaded asynchronously. Which means whether `this.listOfCountries` is populated or not depends on *when* exactly you're trying to access it. `ngOnInit` kicks off the request, but your app will render for the first time before the countries are loaded.

Comment: @ChrisG I see, that makes a lot of sense. So how would I go about checking when the array is fully populated before using it?

Comment: When do you need `listOfCountries` first? Will it be used in the UI or also in the TS-file? I mean, directly after ngOnOnit? It wouldn't be a problem when you need it in the UI directly and somewhen later in the TS.

Comment: @Lynx242 It is being used in the same TS file. So in another function, the for loop is being called. That function is being called in ```ngAfterViewInit```.

Comment: Okay. I see. Let me check.

Comment: This is precisely what observables are for. You need to 1. do everything that depends on the list of countries *inside the callback* you're passing to `.subscribe()` 2. write your template in a way that it can deal with the list of countries being empty/undefined. Typically people use conditional rendering, i.e. `ngIf` / `ng-if` or whatever angular is using.

Comment: @ChrisG I see, I'll revisit how subscribe works to help me fully understand this. Thanks so much!

Comment: It's not that complicated. What happens is: 1. start 2. ngOnInit fires 3. API requests starts 4. app renders for the first time 5. ngAfterViewInit is called 6. time passes 7. request finishes 8. subscribe callback function runs, sets `this.listOfCountries` 9. app renders again

Comment: Ah I see... I thought the request would have finished immediately. Still trying to wrap my head around it all. Thanks for the simple explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, referring to your provided code [here](https://github.com/jess-mw/desk23/blob/threejs/src/app/globe/globe.component.ts), you have 2 options:

**Option 1**

Create a method that is called when the value is present. Do not rely on `AfterViewInit`.

```
listOfCountries: Country[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
   this.countryService.getCountryData().subscribe((countries) => {
     this.listOfCountries = countries;

     this.initDependencies();
   });
 }

 initDependencies() {
   this.setScene();
   this.setCamera();
   this.setRenderer();
   this.setControls();

   this.createLightGroup();
   this.createGlobe();

   this.animate();
   this.setAllPoints(this.currentYear);
 }
```

**Option 2**

Only call `this.setAllPoints(this.currentYear);` separately, when the value is present.

```
listOfCountries: Country[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
   this.countryService.getCountryData().subscribe((countries) => {
     this.listOfCountries = countries;
     
     this.setAllPoints(this.currentYear);
   });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.setScene();
   this.setCamera();
   this.setRenderer();
   this.setControls();

   this.createLightGroup();
   this.createGlobe();

   this.animate();
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! This makes so much more sense now. I think I need to revisit how the subscribe works and fully understand it.

Comment: What's with all the scene / camera / etc. stuff? This answer is helpful but will confuse newbies for sure in its current state.

Comment: @Chris G: I adjusted my answer. Now there is a reference to the link Hamza Qureshi provided. Sorry, I thought everybody had seen this in the conversation above.

Comment: @ChrisG it has to do with three js. I am building a globe to represent the earth and plotting coordinate points so that countries are clickable etc. Feel free to check out the github where we are currently in the process of documenting everything: https://github.com/jess-mw/desk23

Comment: @Hamza Qureshi: You're welcome. Glad to hear that it works. 

Answer (score 0):

You see the same error in both cases.

It happens because you initialize `listOfCountries` with an empty value, the value will be assigned to the `listOfCountries` property only when the subscription is called (after the `countryService` responded).

So, you need either put a default value `listOfCountries: Country[] = [];` or check if the `listOfCountries` is array before read the value.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So when I initialise it as an empty array ```listOfCountries: Country[] = [];``` I then get 0 items in my array. So the data isn't loaded in. In another tutorial I followed, I didn't have to initialise but it worked anyway. I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: Depends on the time when you try to access the data from the array.
If you wait until the response is processed and the subscription is called then it will work, if not you'll get an error from your question.

Comment: So I am currently trying to print a value of the array within ```ngoninit``` right after I load in the data from the service into the array ```this.listOfCountries```. I am not sure if this is an appropriate time? I feel like since it is right after, the response must have been processed by then